# C# Why is Serial.WriteLine() so slow?

Tags: c#, serial-port

When I want to program a Teensy 3.5 micro-controller, I send it a .HEX file via a hardware serial port. I have two ways of doing this; one way is to use a serial comms app like Tera Term to send the file, and another way is via a small C# command-line app I wrote to do the same thing.

When I send a 3000+ line Hex file to the micro-controller, it takes approximately 14 seconds. When I do the same thing with my C# program, it takes twice as long (or longer!).  The baud rate for both Tera Term and my C# program are the same, and of course the Teensy setup is common to both.
When I looked as the serial transfer using a digital scope,  I see the following (same time scale in both photos):

[image]

[image]

The first photo shows the transfer when using Tera Term, and the second one shows the transfer when using my C# program using Serial.WriteLine() to transfer file contents line-by-line, as shown below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using System.Diagnostics;

/*
Small console app to facilitate over-the-air (OTA) updates to a Teensy 3.x/4.x controller,
using VS2019 with the Visual Micro extension as the Arduino IDE. It is called by a post-build
'hook' statement in a file called 'board.txt' located in whatever Teensy program is 
being updated.  This app does the following:

 - Extract the project path and selected COMPORT number from the arguments to the call to Main()
 - Opens a UART serial port connection to the Teensy, typically one provided by a BT adaptor
   operating in 'pass-through' mode. The serial port COMPORT number is passed into this app
   as an argument.
 - Sends whatever command is required to put the existing Teensy firmware into 'update' mode
 - Using the path of the updating program (passed in as an argument), locates the .HEX file 
   associated with the project, and sends it's contents to the Teensy, one line at a time, counting
   lines and confirming checksums line-by-line
 - Compares the number of lines sent to the Teensy with the number of lines received by the Teensy,
   and if there is a match, allows the Teensy update process to complete; otherwise aborts
*/

namespace TeensyFlash
{  
    class Program
    {
        const string startCmdStr = "U"; //used in sketch's 'GetUserInput()' to start upload sequence
        static string rcvStr = string.Empty;
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        private static bool bTimedOut;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Extract the build path and selected COMPORT number from the arguments to the call to Main()
            Console.WriteLine("Teensy Flash Console");
            Console.WriteLine("Number of arguments in args = {0}\n", args.Length);
            int argindex = 0;
            string comPortStr = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                if (item.Contains("COM"))
                {
                    comPortStr = args[argindex];
                }

                argindex++;
            }

            string build_path = args[0];
            string projectName = args[args.Length - 1];
            projectName = projectName.Substring(0, projectName.Length - 4); //remove extension
            build_path = build_path.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Trim();
            string hexfilename = build_path + "\\" + projectName + ".hex";
            Console.WriteLine("path = {0}", build_path);
            Console.WriteLine("comport = {0}", comPortStr);
            Console.WriteLine("build name = {0}", projectName);
            Console.WriteLine("path to HEX file = {0}", hexfilename);

            try
            {
                Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(hexfilename);
                foreach (string item in lines)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("this took " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " Msec");



            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Opening Serial Port...");

            try
            {
                SerialPort _serport = new SerialPort(comPortStr, 115200);
                _serport.WriteTimeout = 1000;
                _serport.WriteBufferSize = 20480;
                _serport.Open();
                _serport.DiscardOutBuffer();
                _serport.DiscardInBuffer();
                Thread.Sleep(100);


                Console.WriteLine("Sending Trigger Character " + startCmdStr);
                Console.WriteLine(startCmdStr);
                _serport.Write(startCmdStr);


                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for 'waiting' from Teensy...");
                rcvStr = string.Empty;
                aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                //aTimer.Interval = 5000;
                aTimer.Interval = 25000;
                aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

                aTimer.Start();
                
                while (!rcvStr.Contains("waiting") && !bTimedOut)
                {
                    if (_serport.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                        rcvStr = _serport.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
                aTimer.Stop();

                if (bTimedOut)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Timed out waiting for 'waiting' response from Teensy");
                }
                else
                {
                    //if we get to here, the Teensy is ready to receive HEX file contents
                    Console.WriteLine("Received " + rcvStr + " from Teensy");
                     
                    Stopwatch stopwatch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    int numlines = 0;
                    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(hexfilename);
                    foreach (string item in lines)
                    {
                        numlines++;
                        _serport.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("total lines = {0}, time = {1} mSec", numlines, stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);

                    //now we wait for Teensy to emit "hex file: xx lines xx bytes..." and then "enter xx to flash..."
                    aTimer.Start();
                    while (!rcvStr.Contains("hex file:") && !bTimedOut)
                    {
                        if (_serport.BytesToRead > 0)
                        {
                            rcvStr = _serport.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                    aTimer.Stop();
                    aTimer.Dispose();

                    if (bTimedOut)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Timed out waiting for 'hex file' response from Teensy");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //extract number of lines from Teensy string, and compare with numlines.
                        //If they match, then send the number back to Teensy to complete the update.
                        //Otherwise, send '0' to abort

                        int colonIdx = rcvStr.IndexOf(':');
                        int lineIdx = rcvStr.IndexOf("lines");
                        string compareStr = rcvStr.Substring(colonIdx + 1, lineIdx - colonIdx - 1);
                        compareStr = compareStr.Trim();
                        int numTeensyLines = Convert.ToInt16(compareStr);

                        Console.WriteLine("sent {0} teensy replied {1}", numlines, numTeensyLines);
                        if (numTeensyLines == numlines)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("numlines {0} matches numTeensyLines {1} - send confirmation",
                                numlines, numTeensyLines);

                            _serport.WriteLine(compareStr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            try
            {

                }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        static string chksum(string input)
        {
            int TwosComplement(string s)
            {
                if (s.Length % 2 != 0)
                    throw new FormatException(nameof(input));

                var checksum = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2)
                {
                    var value = int.Parse(s.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

                    checksum = (checksum + value) & 0xFF;
                }

                return 256 - checksum & 0xFF;
            }

            //return string.Concat(":", input, " ", TwosComplement(input).ToString("X2"));
            return TwosComplement(input).ToString("X2");
        }
        private static void SetTimer()
        {
            // Create a timer with a two second interval.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            //aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                              e.SignalTime);
            bTimedOut = true;
        }
    }

}
```

The code that actually does the file transfer is:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
int numlines = 0;
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(hexfilename);
foreach (string item in lines)
{
    numlines++;
    _serport.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.WriteLine("total lines = {0}, time = {1} mSec", numlines, stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

When the '_serport.WriteLine(item);' line is commented out, the reported elapsed time is 0 mSec, as expected - so the 'ReadAllLines()' step isn't the problem.

Anyone have an idea why the 'WriteLine(item)' processing is so slow?

Comment: Would be good to have an example of an HEX file used as input.
Nevertheless, don't forget that C# strings use utf-16 encoding, so every character will be 2 bytes, whereas with ASCII / utf-8 encoding, each character would be 1 byte. That could explain the "twice as long" that you experienced. You could try to directly send the UTF-8 converted bytes from the string. Example usage: `byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(yourString);` and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864198/can-i-use-serialport-write-to-send-byte-array for how to send bytes.

Comment: If that helped, I'll turn this comment into an answer.

Comment: And what if you just send the whole file in one go, not line by line? So, one Write call.

Comment: @Pac: Your analysis is probably good, but I believe the proper way to set the mapping is to use [the SerialPort.Encoding Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.encoding?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

Comment: Are you sure you know what you're looking at on the scope? The time scale on your scope is too slow. When one (screen) division represents 20millisec, then that time interval has the capacity for almost 230 bytes at 115200 baud. So each blip in your lower photo probably represents a line of data (e.g. maybe 60 bytes per blip). That means the idle time is between the transmission of lines and calls to `_serport.WriteLine(item);`  There's no indication that "more" data is being transmitted, i.e. "wrong encoding" as previously guessed.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346129/serial-port-communication-issue-in-wpf-using-vspe

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of the method itself with the device, but I found on the same site an inquiry and means for it that help you

[stackoverflow: console writeline slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272177/console-writeline-slow)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you think another Stack Overflow Q&A directly answers the question without anything more specific to add, the preferred way is to "flag" the question (buttons at the bottom), then choose "duplicate" reason, and paste the link there. Alternatively, when you reach sufficient reputation you'll be able to add a comment.